# LibreOffice Writer - Start Numbering Equation from specific number and level using fn+F3 (Ex.: start from 2.2)

Tags: libreoffice

When I use fn+F3,  it starts numbering equations from 1. What should I do to start from 2.2, for example.

Comment: The nearest I can find is that, if your document uses [outline numbering](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Outline_Numbering), you can edit the field to add **Numbering by chapter**. Beyond that, I think you would need to define a custom field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagining an equation number as (number of chapter . number of equation)

(2.3) = chapter 2, equation 3

---

All chapters have to be defined with a title formated as "Heading 1".

Between the first and the second chapter all the equations will be (1 . number of equation).

Between the second and the third chapter all equations will be (2. number of equation)...

---

If you want that your first chapter start from an specific number (Ex.: 3) you should:

Format>Bullets and Numbering>click level 1>start at 3

In my opinion it's also interesting to show sublevels in headings:

Format>Bullets and Numbering>select 1-10 (on the left) > show sublevels 10

---

**Finally, 2 clicks on the formula's number and choose level 1,2 or 3... according to your necessity.**

Answer (score 0):

Create the number field as normal. Then select it and right click,from the menu select **edit fields.** You should then get a pop up with **numbering by chapter** as a selectable list